# Enforcing user login before continuing to next page

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Good day, I am creating an application that requires a user to log in using Google. I have gone through a tutorial (using Firebase) and have successfully managed to get the login system to work.

**My issue:** The user can bypass the login by clicking on the "Sign in with Google" then clicking on the side of the screen to exit the log in.

[image]

**Assumption:** In the login-page.dart file: My `_signInButton()` function `onPressed()` is not correct in asserting that a user is logged in.

**Help needed:** Rewriting/reworking my current code to send the user back to the home screen if they do not sign in. Only allow user to proceed if user has been authenticated.

**login-page.dart file:**

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image(image: AssetImage("images/localhourlogo.png"), height: 80.0),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              _signInButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _signInButton() {
    return OutlineButton(
      splashColor: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: () {                           //****problem area?*****
          signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return MyTabs();
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        );
      },
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
      highlightElevation: 0,
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(image: AssetImage("images/google_logo.png"), height: 35.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Text(
                'Sign in with Google',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**sign-in.dart file:**

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
  await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}

void signOutGoogle(context) async{
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
  Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/"));
  print("User Sign Out");
}
```

**Extra information:**
Here is the tutorial I followed: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-implementing-google-sign-in-71888bca24ed

Thank you very much for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code a bit. Returning an string at `signInWithGoogle()` is a bad manner to check if the login was successful or not. But, for now I will let the code equal and only change it a bit to fix the error. In your actual code, you always return a string saying 'succeeded', and you are not checking if something went bad. For that reason, I added a try catch bloc.

```dart
try {
    GoogleSignInAccount user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    //The rest of your code
   return 'Succeed';
} catch (error) {
    return 'Error';
}
```

And at `login-page.dart` I change the `onPressed()` at `_signInButton()`:

```dart
onPressed: () async{
    String result = await signInWithtGoogle();
    if(result == 'Succeed'){
        //Send the user to the tab page like you did
    }else{
        //Reload login page
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't understand there the "try" part fits in

Comment: The try bloc is inside your `signInWithGoogle()` function, enclosing all from `GoogleSignInAccount user = await googleSignIn.signIn();` to `return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';` but again, changing the return statement for the one I showed above